# Why is request.file always undefined when using Multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ubuntu, multer

When I use Multer for NodeJS to receive files through HTTP, the req.file object is undefined. I can see the files ending up in the correct folder, but with gibberish names. Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using Apache2 with Ubuntu.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({dest: '/var/www/185.86.150.191/uploads'}).any());

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.baseURL)
   console.log(req.path)
   console.log(req.file.name);
   console.log(req.file.path);
   console.log(req.file.type);
   var file = __dirname + "/" + req.file.name;

   fs.readFile( req.file.file.path, function (err, data) {
      fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
         if( err ) {
            console.log( err );
            } else {
               response = {
                  message:'File uploaded successfully',
                  filename:req.file.file.name
               };
            }

         console.log( response );
         res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
      });
   });    
})
```

The entire object is not undefined. I can access req.path without any issues, however the application crashes when it reaches req.file.name, because req.file is undefined.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at /home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/server.js:20:24
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Immediate. (/home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53:37)
>       at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:440:18)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

One fix I found was to make the destination path absolute, but it has not helped. The req.file object is still undefined.

The client side looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>File Upload Testing</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h3>File Upload:</h3>
      Select a file to upload: <br />

      <form action = "http://185.86.150.191/node/file_upload" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
         <br />
         <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly there is a problem with how you are sending the file. What does the client side code look like?

Comment: @Quentin Woops, completely forgot to add client side! I've edited it in now.

Comment: Are you making an HTTP request to Apache and then having it reverse proxy to Node.js? What happens if you make the request directly to Node.js? (I don't think it will help, but that would eliminate an Apache configuration issue as a possible factor)

Comment: @Quentin I'm routing the request through Apache, yes. I'm unsure how I can eliminate that step though, as the NodeJS application is local-hosted on a terminal only Linux server.

Comment: Run a test instance of the Node code on a different computer? Make the HTTP request to it from Lynx running on the terminal?

Comment: @Quentin I'm currently stuck at work. I will test the code on a different computer when I get home! Why am I even developing through SSH, this is stupid. I should just make it on a normal computer then port it over later.

Comment: I am having the same issue. All data on the object is recieved on the server(nodejs) running on local host proxied by nginx. When in development mode all was fine. I launch my app on linux vm connected in google vm and in production file.original name is suddenly missing the whole name except the extension its freaking weird. Will see if i can try replicating without nginx not sure whats gonna happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `req.files` and not `req.file`

Comment: I checked the documentation. When using `upload.single` it is `file`, singular.

Comment: @Quentin I think you don't need to add that code. Because you set .any(), it is allready inside req.files

Answer (score 0):

I have write the sample example, check the above example, hope this helps for you.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});

app.post('/upload', upload.single(), function (req, res) {
 console.log(req.file)
})
```